# clicking on File Explorer opens command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

clicking on File EXplorer in Taskbar opens cmd with the window title of "File Explorer" !
Also using Win+E keyboard shortcut does the same thing!!!

What is wrong here?
Any solution?

Win 10 64bit (anniversary update)

Comment: Go to `C:\Windows\ ` and make sure `explorer.exe` has not been replaced by some batch file or command prompt shortcut.

Comment: I even replaced explorer.exe with a copy from my other win 10 , still the problem exists. I am sure this file is OK

Comment: I can open file explorer via: Win+R keys and then typing eg: a folder location like c:\windows\ and pressing Enter. but when I want to open explorer using Win+E it opens a commandprompt instead!

Comment: use process monitor to see what windows is doing to run explorer: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Comment: Any idea what command is being executed when pressing WinKey + E? You can use Task Manager to find it out. [Configure Task Manager to Display Full Path and Command Line of Running Processes](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/configure-task-manager-to-display-full-path-of-running-processes/)

Comment: it runs cmd.exe

Comment: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"

Comment: Also, is "cmd" the default action when you right-click a folder?

Comment: No, that works fine

Comment: I can open folders inside windows explorer by double clicking or right click and select "open"

Comment: have you used procmon to see what windows is doing?